# how to get current date/time in PHP from user

Tags: php, date

I have to add form in which user can select date and time, but I want user can only select date and time of future not past date time, for the eg user have to select date time for an appointment.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this a webpage? You can use a datetime picker, many out there, there is no restriction on future dates.

Comment: yes its a webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily instantiate Datepicker widgets with http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and using .formatDate(), can limit your input date and time to maxDate.